# Understanding the flow of a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to learn how structs work in C. I am familiar with constructors in Java. Now, I have an example of creating a tree in C with structs.

```
struct a_tree_node{
      int value;
      struct a_tree_node *leftPTR, *rightPTR;
};
```

I am currently trying to visualize how this works, I am a little confused because this struct contains itself.

Comment: Seriously? The Java equivalent looks **more** like "containing itself" than the C or C++ version, because of Java's reference semantics and lack of pointer/reference markup.

Comment: Java constructors do not relate to C structs in any way. They are two different concepts. A constructor in Java is a method, a function, that contains executable code. A struct in C is only a data structure.

Answer (score 6):

> I am a little confused because this struct contains itself.

The struct doesn't contain itself, but rather two pointers to the same kind of structure. That's the key point to understand.

The struct containing itself would be nonsense and wouldn't compile because it's an infinitely recursive dependency.

Comment: So the struct contains 2 pointers that point to the type struct a_tree_node?

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to understand that they were pointers pointing to other a_tree_node structs, which was very confusing to grasp at first.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion is comparing a struct to a constructor in Java. The closest equivalent in Java would be `class`:

```
class ATreeNode{
      int value;
      ATreeNode left;
      ATreeNode right;
}
```

As the other answers have said, the left and right node in the struct are pointers - much like (but not quite the same as) references from Java.

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` doesn't contain it self. It contains two pointers to its type. A very important distinction. Pointers are not of the type the point to but can rather be dereferenced into what they point to at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't contain itself it contains two pointers to the same defenition. The * in front of the leftPTR and rightPTR point to memory location where other a_tree_node's are stored.

Answer (score 1):

The struct is defined in such a way that it forms a linked list. Inside the struct you define two pointers to structs. So, the struct does not contain itself, rather, it contains two pointers to two different instantiations of a struct. It is even possible the pointer is a pointer to the struct itself.

Answer (score 0):

When coming from Java, you already know the necessary concepts, but lack the rigor C enforces on the concepts of data and pointers. leftPtr is just like a variable of class type (like Object) in Java, that is, it points to another object, might be Null or might point to another object.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a linked list of int representing a binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

It contains the address of a simlar structure.
Like lets take a tree node.

it means that a single tree node also stores the address of two other similar tree nodes.

Answer (score -1):

Here in the question contains a pointer to `struct a_tree_node`.
The size of a pointer type is always constant i.e. `sizeof(unsigned integer)`
so it won't create any problem in defining the size of a `struct a_tree_node`.
It will not be a nested `struct`... :) :)

Comment: Pretty sure `sizeof(struct a_tree_node *) == sizeof(unsigned integer)` is a bad assumption.

Comment: in general scenario ...the pointer size is equal to the size of unsigned integer..... it may vary from vendor to vendor ... :)

Comment: I think "the size of a pointer to a struct is fixed, i.e. it is not determined by the size of the struct itself" would be a more accurate way to express what you're trying to say. There's no need to compare pointers to integers, especially not a specific integer type to illustrate that the size of the pointer is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct a_tree_node{int value;struct a_tree_node *leftPTR, *rightPTR; };
```

This code will work fine as we are referring pointer to structure not its object as size of pointer is not data type specific. It will depend on how much bit is your OS effectively your integer will take how much byte
e.g on gcc `sizeof(int)` is 4 so `sizeof(leftPTR)` is also same
so at run time there will be no recursion `sizeof(a_tree_node)=12` (Not considering structure padding as it is compiler specific)

```
struct a_tree_node{int value;struct a_tree_node left;};
```

This declaration will leads to error as compiler wouldn't be able to compute its size
goes in infite recursion.

Comment: *"`sizeof(int)` is 4 so `sizeof(leftPTR)` is also same"* not quite an accurate statement.

Comment: ya its an accurate statment .. just try to run this program int main(){ int a; int *p; printf("%d%d",sizeof(a),sizeof(p));} as it depends on OS architecture means how many bits can be sent at a time